# Angular 2 PUT content with uri/list content type(multiple elements)

Tags: angular, spring-data-rest

How to send the following in Angular 2 typescript?

To send multiple URIs we have to separate them by a line break:

curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list"
  --data-binary @uris.txt http://localhost:8080/authors/1/books

The uris.txt file contains the URIs of the books, each on a separate line:

http://localhost:8080/books/1
http://localhost:8080/books/2

I know how to send PUT htt request, but didn't find solution to send multiple elements in a PUT request!

I can't produce a content like this:
http://localhost:8080/books/1
http://localhost:8080/books/2

Typescript puts always "" in string and i'm getting an error on the server side.

I can send one like this:

```
 return this.http
    .put(`${this.apiUrl + this.quizesUrl}/${quiz.id}${this.questionsUrl}`
        , `${this.apiUrl + this.questionsUrl}/4`, QuizesService.OPTIONS_URI_LIST) // ...using put request
    .map(this.handleSingleResponse) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
    .catch(this.handleError) // ...errors if any
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('After updateQuestion request...');
    })
```

;

How to send multiple from a collection?

Comment: are you trying to update multiple entities with a single `PUT` request?

Comment: yes, Quiz has multiple questions and i want to assign all of them in a single request. Content type: uri/list has this capability.
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
saveQuizQuestionAssignment(quiz: Quiz) {
  console.log(`${this.apiUrl + this.quizesUrl}/${quiz.id}${this.questionsUrl}`);
  console.log(this.createQuizQuestionRequest(quiz));
  return this.http
        .put(`${this.apiUrl + this.quizesUrl}/${quiz.id}${this.questionsUrl}`
            , this.createQuizQuestionRequest(quiz), QuizesService.OPTIONS_URI_LIST) 
        .map(this.handleSingleResponse) 
        .catch(this.handleError) 
        .finally(() => {
          console.log('After updateQuestion request...');
        }); 
}

createQuizQuestionRequest(quiz: Quiz) {
  var putRequestLine = '';
  quiz.questions.forEach(question => {    
    putRequestLine += `${this.apiUrl + this.questionsUrl + '/' + question.id}`+'\n';       
  });
  return putRequestLine;
}
```

I have found the very easy solution. /when you are tired hard to find the easiest things/

The 'createQuizQuestionRequest' function appends the uri-list content and it is accepted by the backend. Then the request will update the quiz-question assignment in the relation table(quiz_question).

So the code is equivalent of the following request sent in postman:

[image]